# set UIDatePicker 1 hour later as current time

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I think the title says it all. 
I can get the current time, but I need the current time + 1 hour too.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY hh:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
myUILabel.text = dateString;
```

How do I format the date so it will add 1 hour to the current time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *dateAfter_1hour = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
UIDatePicker *datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datepicker setDate:dateAfter_1hour animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift:

```
theDateAnHourFromNow = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(3600)
```

Comment: The question is specifically about Objective-C